# Automatic kerberos ticket initialization on login

Tags: kde, login, kerberos

I'm using `ksshaskpass` to add my password protected keys into `ssh-agent` upon logging into KDE, is there something similar for kerberos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would look into using [pam-krb5](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/).

On Debian and Ubuntu, it should be `apt-get install libpam-krb5`.

The PAM configuration would look something like:

```
auth required pam_unix.so
auth optional pam_krb5.so try_first_pass
```

or

```
auth required pam_unix.so
auth optional pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
```

in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

It takes the password you used to authenticate locally, e.g. the password in `/etc/shadow`, and then tries to use the same one as your Kerberos password.

If your Kerberos password is the same as your system password, you don't need to type it again.

If your Kerberos password is different from your system password, what happens depends on whether you used `try_first_pass` or `use_first_pass`:

- `try_first_pass` will ask you for your Kerberos password
- `use_first_pass` won't ask you, but you'll have to run `kinit` yourself later

Note that this probably makes ksshaskpass redundant too, because you can also have:

```
auth required pam_unix.so
auth optional pam_ssh.so try_first_pass
auth optional pam_krb5.so try_first_pass
```

On Debian and Ubuntu, that requires installing [libpam-ssh](http://pam-ssh.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yeah I know about this, but I would like some solution that works with different passwords.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Can you elaborate?  `try_first_pass` or no option should work in that case.

Comment: How would this work if my kerberos username is different from the local username? E.g. `gert` versus `gertvdijk`.

Comment: It would be great to have kinit using a keyring, does someone know about something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Kerberos would be integrated with PAM pam_krb5.so.  It will attempt to acquire a Kerberos ticket based on your username and the password you supply.  It can also use that to verify whether you are allowed to login, but that can be set to ignore if you just want the ticket.  It needs to be added as both an auth and a session module, probably also password if you plan to keep your Kerberos password in sync with your desktop.  If you plan to use Kerberos for verifying a user's login, you should also setup your keytab file at /etc/krb5.keytab with a key for host/hostname.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM replace hostname and example.com as appropriate for your environment.